# VSCode API get language comment delimiter

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there any way to get the comment delimiters ( eg "#" for Py & "//" in case of Js ) from the vscode api ? I can use the actions "editor.action.addCommentLine" to comment the line, but I am looking for a way to get the delimiter as a string. I don't care about the block comment, I just need single line comment delimiter.